# How to allocate memory in pandas

Tags: pandas, dynamic-memory-allocation

I read about 30000 files. Each file is a csv with the same numbers of cols and rows. Thus, I know exactly the size of the matrix.

What I do is:

```
#allocate a pandas Dataframe
data_n=pd.Dataframe()

for i in range(0,30000):
    #read the file and storeit to a temporary Dataframe
    tmp_n=pd.DataFrame({'Ping':Counter_4eh*m256,'SN':SN_4eh*m256,'Frequency':CF_4eh*m256,'Sonar_speed':CsT_4eh*m256,'Pulse_length':SL_4eh*m256,'Nomimal_point_angle':BA_4eh,'Absrorption':AC_4eh*m256,'Range':R})
    # now append in the "big" dataframe
    data_n=pd.concat([data_n,tmp_n],ignore_index=True)
```

This is time consuming. Is anyway  can preallocate the data_n and add directly in the big matrix? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `pd.concat` may be very inefficient, copying all the already added data over and over, at every iteration. That might take much more time than creating and loading the small DataFrame.

What you could do is to allocate empty numpy arrays for the complete data (for all 30000 files), and then fill them iteratively by index. When all files are loaded and all numpy arrays are filled, combine them into a single Pandas DataFrame.

Only when getting rid of the `concat` should you start optimizing the preallocation when loading the files.

Comment: Yes, that's what I ended up doing. Preallocate an numpy array and convert it to pandas in the end.